# How can i test for the type of a method return in kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, tdd

So i am trying to develop some TDD skills and am doing a kata found online.

I want to test that my mehthod will always return a list to any given valid argument.

I tried

```
    @Test
    fun factorsOfShouldReturnAList(){
        assertThat(prime.factorsOf(1), `is`(List::class))
    }
```

but my test always fails with the following error:

```
"java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <interface java.util.List (Kotlin reflection is not available)>
     but: was <[]>
Expected :is <interface java.util.List (Kotlin reflection is not available)>
Actual   :<[]>"
```

Comment: How is your `factorsOf()` function declared?

Comment: If `factorsOf()` is in Kotlin, then there shouldn't be a need for such a test in the first place.  If it's declared to return `List<(something)>`, then there's no point testing something that the compiler already guarantees — and if it's not, then it probably should be :-)